# Cambiar una función de Javascript mediante un Input del usuario

Tags: javascript, html5

Hopla a todos, llevo un par de días buscando por internet un método para hacer lo que yo quiero, seguramente sea muy fácil o directamente imposible. Bueno, allá vamos.
Tengo esta función dentro de Javascript que cambia el contenido de un XML

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction1(xml) {
    var x, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0];
    txt = x.nodeValue + "<br>";
    x.nodeValue="TEXTO A CAMBIAR";
    txt += x.nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("cambiar").innerHTML = txt
}
```

Mi pregunta es si con un input del usuario de este tipo

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Some text...">
```

Con una función de este tipo asociado

```
  function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("cambio").innerHTML = x;}
```

Podría hacer que cambiara el contenido de la primera función, es decir, donde ahora pone "TEXTO A CAMBIAR", apareciera el input del usuario...
Espero haberme explicado. Es decir, quiero cambiar mediante un input una función que ya existe en el .js.

Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que la segunda función devuelva el valor del input:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  document.getElementById("cambio").innerHTML = x;
  return x;
}
```

Y luego usar esa función en la primera:

```
function myFunction1(xml) {
    var x, xmlDoc, txt;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0];
    txt = x.nodeValue + "<br>";
    x.nodeValue = myFunction2();
    txt += x.nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("cambiar").innerHTML = txt
}
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero no funciona :(

Comment: Simplemente no responde la función. solo la del botón

Comment: He ido probando y el probelma está cuando le meto la función 'return = x'